# looking for vba code to list today between no of dates in excel vba

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with a schedule of date wise samples up to 3 years.
In that sheet how to find a today samples as a popup alert in VBA

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your spreadsheet and its data or a screenshot of that sheet? That will help us get you an answer that's most relevant to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Dear please share your mail id    my Id. Vijayaramaraju4@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

So far as i think, this might ful-fill your purpose, this is a macro code in which it would ask the user to enter the date it want to search in a particular column, you can change the column by changing Range("A:A") to whatever you prefer.

```
Sub Find_Date()
Dim FindString As Date
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = InputBox("Please Enter Date")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
```

End Sub